# Duplicate identifier when declaring types with same name in different files

Tags: typescript

I have a simple TypeScript 'snippets' project, and I've run into an issue where multiple .ts files will have the same type names (eg. Foo).

```
//file-a.ts

type Foo = {

}
```

```
//file-b.ts

type Foo = {

}
```

If I try compile this I get:

```
 error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Foo'.
```

This doesn't make sense to me - as these typings should be specific to the module.

I'm using typescript version 3.7.5, and my tsconfig.json has these properties (everything else defaults):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019' or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
    "outDir": "./dist",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    "rootDir": "./src",                       /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
    "isolatedModules": true,               /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true  /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
  }
}
```

What's going on here here? [The actual code here.](https://github.com/dwjohnston/advancedish-typescript/tree/3cbc6f893404aa99a6a413460d1c51de149cbd9e)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since 4.7 TypeScript has a configuration option for this: the compiler option [`moduleDetection`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#moduleDetection) can be set to `"force"`, which

> ensures that every non-declaration file is treated as a module.

This will treat all inputs as modules (even if they contain no `import` or `export` statement).

Answer (score 16):

If you do not `export` anything from a TypeScript file, it gets compiled in the global scope. To make a `.ts` file an enclosed module you need to `export` at least one thing.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I hate it. Is there a config item that will prevent this behaviour?

Comment: @dwjohnston you can avoid a declaration collision by using a namespace: `namespace FileB { type Foo = {} }`

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60271921/duplicate-identifier-when-declaring-types-with-same-name-in-different-files/74030813#comment106612302_60271965) @dwjohnston In version `4.7` TypeScript introduced a feature for [control over module detection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#control-over-module-detection). See [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74030813/438273).