# Allow Duplicate identifiers (in different .ts files)

Tags: typescript

I'm storing various un-imported .ts files together in the same folder for my own education; they do not form a cohesive app, each is intended to be a "stand-alone" project (ie: run the transpiled .js version from the node terminal)

So in tsconfig.json I've got:

```
"compilerOptions": {
   "rootDir": "./ts_src",
   "outDir": "./ts_out"
},
"include": ["ts_src"]
```

With the files: ts_src/linked_list_1.ts, and ts_src/linked_list.2.ts,

I'm getting the error: "Duplicate identifier 'ListNode'"

How can I configure typescript (and/or how should I organize my files) so that I avoid this error (ie: how can I allow Duplicate identifiers in different .ts files)?

I understand that I could simply use different identifiers, but because I am documenting several different versions of similiar data structures, I'd like to be able to use the same terms in different files.

EDIT:
[Duplicate identifier when declaring types with same name in different files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60271921/duplicate-identifier-when-declaring-types-with-same-name-in-different-files) explains why this happens, however the response from @jsejcksn answers the question in the terms is was posed (about config).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this by configuring [`compilerOptions.moduleDetection`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#moduleDetection) to `"force"`, which

> ensures that every non-declaration file is treated as a module.

This will treat all inputs as modules (even if they contain no `import` or `export` statement).